# Special representation of $N$ as a sum of two squares in two ways

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations

N is an integer which can be written in two ways as the sum of two distinct perfect squares:

$N = a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2$

> Can $$cd = 2ab$$ be satisfied in this case ?

In other words, does the equation system

$$a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$$ $$cd=2ab$$ have an integer solution besides the trivial solution $\ a=b=c=d=0$ ?

Comment: You mean $N=a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=cd=2ab$ ??

Comment: No. We have N = a² + b² = c² + d². Is it possible that the four integers a,b,c,d satisfy the relation cd = 2ab?

Comment: For example 65 = 1² + 8² = 4² + 7². a = 1, b = 8, c = 4 and d = 7.

Comment: cd = 28 <>2ab = 16

Comment: but $cd \ne 2ab$ here

Comment: Okay, so you want $N=a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ and $cd=2ab$ both satisfied together??

Comment: Yes. So my question is "Does there exist N such that c*d = 2*a*b ?"

Comment: For  N < 1000000, there is no solution 
I should like to have a complete demonstration for any N.

Comment: Wolfram alpha says that only possible solution  is $a=b=c=d=0$

Comment: Does Wolfram Alpha provide any demonsration?

Comment: By simple arithmetic the problem is equivalent to show that $\sqrt{\frac{4k-1}{k-1}} \in \mathbb{Q}$ when $k \in \mathbb{N} >1$.

Comment: @Ahmad Please show how you arrived at this equation!

Comment: Let $a = \frac{c d}{2 b}$ then you will have $\frac{c ^2 d^2 }{4 b^2} +b^2 = c^2+d^2$ or $c^2(d^2-4b^2) = 4b^2 (d^2-b^2)$ divide by $d^2-4b^2$ and get square root you will have that $c = 2b \sqrt{\frac{d^2-b^2}{d^2-4b^2}}$ so $ \sqrt{\frac{d^2-b^2}{d^2-4b^2}}$ must be integer, meaning $\frac{d^2-b^2}{d^2-4b^2}=k^2$ for some integer $k$ ,let $k$ be on one side and  $b,d$ on other side gives you that $\frac{d^2}{b^2} = \frac{4k^2-1}{k^2-1}$ taking square root on both sides means that left side is rational number and right side is $\sqrt{\frac{4k^2-1}{k^2-1}}$. @Peter

Comment: @Ahmad Nice, but how did you get rid of the squares ( the final expression does not contain $k^2$, only $k$ ) ?

Comment: @Peter I did mistake in the first comment ....

Comment: Many thanks. I am convinced. BV

Comment: You write c = 2b*sqrt((d^2-b^2)/(d^2-4b^2) so sqrt((d^2-b^2)/(d^2-4b^2) must be integer.

Comment: Why integer? I should say sqrt((d^2-b^2)/(d^2-4b^2) is rational. So the demonstration is not the same with k rational instead of k integer.